# Scope of an exported variable in shell

Tags: shell, variable, subshell

Say I have a script where I have exported a variable as seen below:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo(){
    eval export one=1
}
foo1(){
    eval export two=2
}
(foo)
foo1
echo "one=$one"
echo "two=$two"
```

However I got the following output:

```
root@centos1:~>/tmp/test.sh
one=
two=2
```

What might be reason that I am unable to see value of `$one` and can see `$two`?

Comment: To run it in a subshell

Answer (score 7):

**Global variables** live from the moment they're set up until the moment they're unset or the process ends. Global (nor local) variables are not inherited by unrelated child processes (if the child process is a fork (a subshell) then it gets a copy of everything -- exported or nonexported).

**Global exported variables** are like global variables, but they're also automatically inherited (as part of the process environment) by, even unrelated, child processes. (With exports, you can pass a variable such as `CXXFLAGS` to a process such as `make`, which most definitely isn't a subshell of your shell, and every process that that `make` spawns will also get that variable too.)

In your example `()` creates a subshell, which gets a copy of everything.
The `foo` command modifies the subshell by adding an exported variable and then the subshell ends without ever utilizing the exported variable (no grandchild inheritted it). Now, no information implicitly travels from child processes to parent processes. What children do in their environment has no affect on their parents. That is the reason why your variable `one` is unset.

---

BTW, those `eval`s are an unnecessary `eval` in this context.

Comment: `$one` is not empty but unset. There is a difference between both states.

Comment: @shily thx. fixed

Answer (score 2):

Enclosing a command between `( )` will result in the command being in a sub shell.

This can be useful if one is to pipe, or exit.

For example, the following commands

```
( date ; cmd1 ; cmd2 ) | grep ...
```

will result in concatenating the first 3 commands and giving output to `grep`.

You might consider `{ }`, for which you should refer to the man page for bash ([`bash(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)); here is an excerpt:

> `(list)`
>
>   *`list`*
>   is executed in a subshell environment (see
>   **COMMAND  EXECUTION  ENVIRONMENT**
>   below).   Variable  assignments  and  builtin commands that affect the
>   shell's environment do not remain in effect after the command completes. 
>   The return status is the exit status of
>   *`list`*
>   .
>
> `{ list; }`
>
>   *`list`*
>   is simply executed in the current shell environment.
>   *`list`*
>   must be
>   terminated with a newline or semicolon.   This is known as a
>   *group
>   command.*
>   The return status is the exit status of
>   *`list`*
>   . 
>   Note  that unlike the metacharacters
>   **`(`**
>   and
>   **`)`**
>   ,
>   **`{`**
>   and
>   **`}`**
>   are
>   *reserved
>   words*
>   and must occur where  a
>   *reserved word*
>   is  permitted  to be recognized. 
>   Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated
>   from
>   *`list`*
>   by whitespace or another shell metacharacter.

See also [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216)